# How to use function variables in subfunction

Tags: php

So i have following function: (this should result a latest version)

```
function getLatestVersion($type){

    $searchString['Smarty']     = "php/Smarty-*";
    $searchString['jQuery']     = "js/jQuery-*";
    $searchString['jQueryUI']   = "js/jQueryUI-*";
    $searchString['Bootstrap']  = "js/bootstrap-*";

    $versions = glob($searchString[$type]);

    $latests = array_reduce($versions, function ($latest, $folder) {

        if (!$latest) {
            return $folder;
        }

        $latestNum = preg_replace('!^' . substr($searchString[$type],0,-1) . '!', '', $latest);
        $folderNum = preg_replace('!^' . substr($searchString[$type],0,-1) . '!', '', $folder);

        return version_compare($latestNum, $folderNum, '>') ? $latest : $folder;

    });
    return $latests;
}
```

but this causes a error

```
Notice: Undefined variable: searchString in....
Notice: Undefined variable: type in....
```

**Question:** why cant i use the vars in that subfunction ?

**what i have tried:**

```
....
$latests = array_reduce($versions, function ($latest, $folder) {
    echo $latest, $folder;
    if (!$latest) {
        return $folder;
    }
    global $searchString, $type; //but the variables are empty
    $latestNum = preg_replace('!^' . substr($searchString[$type],0,-1) . '!', '', $latest);
    $folderNum = preg_replace('!^' . substr($searchString[$type],0,-1) . '!', '', $folder);

    return version_compare($latestNum, $folderNum, '>') ? $latest : $folder;

});
....
```

Comment: Where is `$searchString` defined?

Comment: cant you see it ? i declare a array... this works fine... but in the array_reduce callback they are missing

Comment: The use of `array_reduce()` is a bit overkill; a normal loop would be a lot more logical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's quite simple:

```
function ($latest, $folder) use ($searchString, $type) {
```

To use variables from the parent scope, use `use` ;)